# About hard-coded `self`-references in antlr4 grammar files

Tags: javascript, node.js, plsql, antlr4

Got a question about antlr4-grammars:

After generating a PL/SQL-parser and lexer using:

`antlr4 -Dlanguage=JavaScript PlSqlParser.g4 PlSqlLexer.g4`,

I find that the resulting `PlSqlParser.js` and `PlSqlLexer.js` contains the variable `self` which produces `ReferenceError: self is not defined`, when run with the antlr4 node runtime.

The grammar files can be found here: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/plsql

As you'll see, both the the `*.g4` files in this listing, actually contains this variable hard-coded in some of its statements, e.g. in PlSqlParser.g4 at line 1377:

```
alter_view_editionable
    : {self.isVersion12()}? (EDITIONABLE | NONEDITIONABLE)
    ;
```

Is it correct to assume this grammar, then, is hard-coded to be run in a browser-context, in which `self` would reference the `Window` object? So all I need to do, is replace `self` with `this` in the `*.g4`-files to make it compatible with node?

Comment: `self` doesn't work for all languages.  Needs to be `this` for JavaScript.  It looks like this PR (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/commit/34a76ff2cce2d42b18050eddf12e38cec3ae3269#diff-dacd39dcc1d10347e53ef7f44716047839e8d21f09f6834c72991391ed8648da) addressed the `self` issue for many languages but not for JavaScript (it is addressed for Typescript).  You may have luck applying the same change to the JavaScript target.  It just adds `this.self = this` to the constructor so that `self` works.  (@kaby76 made the PR, perhaps he knows more about the exclusion of JavaScript)

Comment: There should be a "transformGrammars.py" file that modifies the two grammar files to remove the "self." prefix prior to running the Antlr tool. The grammars are intended to be shared across all targets, but each has a different way to access the "method" or "function" associated with the parser and lexer base classes. The sql/plsql grammar is currently not tested for JavaScript so it may not even work if this is fixed. I will check and update.

Comment: OK, I've made a PR to fix the JavaScript target for sql/plsql. Basically, there were a few things wrong in the .js base class files, and missing the transformGrammar.py file that needs to be run "python transformGrammar.py" in the grammar directory before running Antrl4 tool on *.g4. The parser is not that quick, which is probably why I don't have it tested. I haven't had time to analyse the Antlr JavaScript runtime lately (on PHP now). https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/pull/3000

Comment: So, the short answer to your question/comment to replace "self." with "this.", yes, that is what exactly needs to be done. Thanks for pointing this problem out.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answers here. I replaced the `self` keyword with the `this` keyword in the *.g4 files. And it is able to walk the parsed tree resulting from the code of several PL/SQL packages (several thousand lines of code). If you prefer, I'll compile your answers into a a single answer, and use that to answer this post. Otherwise feel free to write your own answer, and I'll accept that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @kaby76, there was a grammar transformation step (replacing `self` with `this`) missing when generating the JavaScript target for PL/SQL.

It's now been [fixed](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/commit/38857b99fbb6effa129e2d49182d3814013f8e46), and merged into the master branch of antlr/grammars-v4.